# Angular scope items not applies after item change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have items service,items list controller, and item details controller:

```
.state('dashboard.items', {
        url: '/items',
        templateUrl: '/js/components/dashboard/items/items.html',
        controller:'itemsListCtrl'
      })
      .state('dashboard.items.details', {
        url: '/:id',
        templateUrl: '/js/components/dashboard/items/itemDetails.html',
        controller: 'itemDetailsCtrl',
        resolve:{
          items: function (ItemService) {
            if(!ItemService.items)
              ItemService.getAll().then(function (res) {
                ItemService.items = res.data;
              });
          }
        }
      })

app.factory('ItemService', function ($http) {
  var itemsFactory = {};
  itemsFactory.getAll = function () {
    return $http.get('/items');
  }

  itemsFactory.update = function () {
    itemsFactory.items[0].name = "sadasd";
  }

  return itemsFactory;
})

app.controller('itemsListCtrl', function($scope, $state, ItemService){
  if(!ItemService.items) {
    ItemService.getAll().then(function (res) {
      ItemService.items = res.data;
      $scope.items = ItemService.items;
    });
  }else{
    $scope.items = ItemService.items;
  }
})


app.controller('itemDetailsCtrl', function ($scope, items, ItemService) {
  $scope.item = ItemService.items[0];
  $scope.item.name = "abc" ;

  $scope.update = function(){
    ItemService.update();
  }
})
```

I have ng-click button which invokes the edit() function.
I made it simple for the example, when doing the update, and edit the item name, the item that presents in the list doesnt change.
I dont know what I miss here. The list sits in the service, and both controllers use it for their purposes.

What am I doing wrong? What is best practice for this scenario?

**Update 1**
Found something weird. When I edit the item in the controller initialization, it changes the original value globally. When it happens via the edit()  method, it doesn't. What happnes?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `ItemService.getAll()` being called twice?

Comment: I check if the itemService.items already exists, so no I guess.

Comment: $http calls are asynchronous, so it may not exist when you do the check.

Comment: So what is the best practice for doing it?

Answer (score 0):

$http.get returns a promise that it will return your data, so in .then you can do your stuff and it will execute when done(async)

```
$http.get('/items').then(function successCallback(response) {
 // this callback will be called asynchronously
 // when the response is available

 return response.data;//this is your data
}, function errorCallback(response) {
 // called asynchronously if an error occurs
 // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

Comment: I know how it works. This is the same as returning the promise only and then set the list from the controller.

Comment: Maybe use the error callback to see where it gets stuck? When you debug does 'getAll()' fill the $scope.items[]?